# C++ Passing arrays by reference to a function but contents remain unchanged

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a program to solve an Economics model. First, I declare a namespace as follows:

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    const int d1{10};
    const int d2{5};
    const int d3{7};
    double array[d1][d2][d3]={};
}
```

Then, I have a function that modifies `array`:

```
void doSomething(double (&array)[myNameSpace::d1][myNameSpace::d2][myNameSpace::d3])
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0, j=0, k=0; i<myNameSpace::d1,j<myNameSpace::d2,k<myNameSpace::d3; i++,j++,k++)
        array[i][j][k]=i+j+k+1.0;
}
```

In the main function I call `doSomething` as:

```
int main()
{
    doSomething(myNameSpace::array);
    for (int i=0;j<myNameSpace::d1;j++)
        std::cout << myNameSpace::array[i][1][1] << std::endl;
}
```

The output I get in the console is:

```
0
0
0
```

Can you provide any guidance on this? I've tried passing `array` without the address-of operator `&`, but then inside `doSomething`, `array` losses the first dimension. Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: `for (int i=0;j<myNameSpace::d1;j++)` this line. You declared `i`' but iterate `j`. Cannot compile.

Comment: You need to turn up your warnings.  [your compiler should be telling you your code is not doing what you think it is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cde7b40f4cda6b72)

Comment: `for (int i=0;j<myNameSpace::d1;j++)` -- Copy and paste the code from your editor into the edit window, don't type it in.

Comment: `for (i=0, j=0, k=0; i<myNameSpace::d1,j<myNameSpace::d2,k<myNameSpace::d3; i++,j++,k++)` - this will only iterate over `array[0][0][0]`, `array[1][1][1]`, `array[2][2][2]`,...

Comment: @AlexG: No, they're not. If you try to pass an array by value, it ends up being a pointer to the first element of the array. This is different than the array being passed by reference, which there is a specific syntax for, and which allows you to maintain the actual type of the array (including its size) in the function.

Comment: Are you hoping to fill the entire array?  Your loop is wrong, and your condition is ONLY actually checking that k<d3.  (The i<d1,j<d2 are evaluated but ignored, due to sequencing of comma operator.)    Also, after each element you increment all 3 variables i,j,k, so they are only touching (0,0,0), (1,1,1)... (7,7,7) and clearly that goes out of range for d2.

Comment: Post minimal, compilable, running example.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `for` loop

```
for (i=0, j=0, k=0; i<myNameSpace::d1,j<myNameSpace::d2,k<myNameSpace::d3; i++,j++,k++)
```

doesn't do what you think it does, and you would've (hopefully) noticed that if you compiled with warnings (warning: *relational comparison result unused*).

It has 2, related, major problems:

1. Since `i<myNameSpace::d1,j<myNameSpace::d2,k<myNameSpace::d3` only returns the value of the last comparison, due to the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do) being used. So, you are effectively iterating until `k<myNameSpace::d3`.
2. The `for` loop you wrote - is just a single loop. It doesn't iterate through all possible combinations of values of `i`, `j`, and `k`, as you might have wanted.

   It initializes `i`, `j`, `k` to 0; checks comparison expression (which, as explained by (1) only checks the value of `k`); and after the code in the loop was run - increments **all** of `i`, `j`, `k` by 1. Hence - you are setting only the `0/0/0`, `1/1/1`, `2/2/2`, `...`, up until `k/k/k` indices of your array. And, because your middle array has a bound, which is smaller than `k` - you invoke undefined behavior by stepping out of bounds.

And, lastly, you are printing only the `i/1/1` index of your array, and since the only one value in the index range `0/1/1`-`d1/1/1` that's set is `1/1/1` - it is, [exactly](http://ideone.com/wOnRKc) what's printed with a non-zero value.

To iterate over the whole array, as, might have been your intention - you should use nested loops, so they would allow all of the loop variables to change independently of one another:

```
for (i=0; i<myNameSpace::d1; i++)
    {
    for (j=0; j<myNameSpace::d2; j++)
        {
        for (k=0; k<myNameSpace::d3; k++)
            {
            array[i][j][k]=i+j+k+1.0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile your code, and I got an error in this line:

> ```
> for (int i=0;j<myNameSpace::d1;j++)
> ```

The variable `j` is undeclared. As you can note, you declared the variable `i` inside the `for` loop, but not `j`. Do you want to loop using `i` or `j`? ...Maybe it's `i` because inside the body of the loop you used it as first-dimension index?

So, maybe you meant this code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < myNameSpace::d1; i++)
    std::cout << myNameSpace::array[i][1][1] << std::endl;
```

In addition, are you sure the loop inside `doSomething` does what you mean?

Or maybe you want to loop using three nested loops for each array dimension?
E.g.:

```
void doSomething(double (&array)[myNameSpace::d1][myNameSpace::d2][myNameSpace::d3])
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < myNameSpace::d1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myNameSpace::d2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < myNameSpace::d3; k++) {
                array[i][j][k] = i + j + k + 1.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in C++ raw arrays are passed by reference, so the `&array` syntax is unnecessary. Moreover, the compiler also ignores the raw array dimensions (`myNameSpace::d1`, etc.) for array parameters. Those may be good for documentation purposes though.

Comment: `array<array<array<double, d3>, d2>, d1>` is way better

Answer (score 0):

If your array declared with those sizes it's way shorter (and readable)to write:

```
void doSomething( declspec(myNameSpace::array) &array )
```

or much better to declare type alias to use it everywhere:

```
using  myArrayType = double[myNameSpace::d1][myNameSpace::d2][myNameSpace::d3];
```

not to mention that d1,d2 and d3 should be `const`. Toset ALL elements of array your loops should look like this:

```
void doSomething( myArrayType &array )
{
   int i,j,k;
   for ( i = 0; i < myNameSpace::d1; i++)
     for ( j = 0; j < myNameSpace::d2; j++)
      for (k = 0; k < myNameSpace::d3; k++)
         array[i][j][k]=i+j+k+1.0;
}
```

Everything written in single for  divided  by comma  is happening in single iteration. There are perverted ways to write it in single for() but I don't recommend that code.
for() loop is very flexible. pretty much it looks like

```
for(expressionFirst; expressionCheck; expressionEach )
    statement to execute
```

**expressionFirst** can be ANY statement OR a single declaration, it executes only once, before loop starts. **expressionCheck** executed at beginning of each iteration, it must be any expression that is contextually convertible to `bool` (i.e. if even `explicit T::operator bool() const;` is applicable in this case), if it returns false, the loop stops. **expressionEach** is any expression that evaluates at end of each iteration.

Equivalent of for()

```
{
   expressionFirst
   while ( expressionCheck ) 
   { 
     statement to execute
     expressionEach; 
   }  
}
```

All expressions are optional, so you can use `for(;;)` - a "forever" loop.

Comma operator you use allows to sequence several expressions, only last one is returned as result. Thus it is called sequence operator. And that's why your loop is wrong.

And you have a typo in main function, which led you to print only the first element of array, no increment of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

for start you have a problem with your for loop 
initialize i and running over j. once I changed it, I received some values.